# Trig Identities when converting to polar form

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates

Been practicing conversions from rectangular form to polar form but got stuck on one question.

rectangular form: $\frac{1}{1+j\omega}$

polar form: $r = \left|\frac{1}{1+j\omega}\right|$, $\phi = -\tan^{-1}(\omega)$

Though I can't figure out how $\phi$ was found for this. The formula being $\phi = \tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})$. could someone show me the derivation for $\phi$?

Comment: Hem, $x=1,y=\omega$, and you take the inverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the complex number 
$$z=\frac{1}{1+j\omega}$$

- To find the **rectangular form**, "rationalize" the denominator. That is
  $$z=\frac{1}{1+j\omega}\cdot \frac{1-j\omega}{1-j\omega}=\frac{1-j\omega}{1+\omega^2}=\frac{1}{1+\omega^2}-j\frac{\omega}{1+\omega^2}=x+jy$$
  Thus
  \begin{align}
  x&=\frac{1}{1+\omega^2}\\
  y&=-\frac{\omega}{1+\omega^2}
  \end{align}
- To find the **polar form**, find the modulus and the angle. 
  \begin{align}
  r&=\left| z\right|=\left| \frac{1}{1+j\omega}\right|=\frac{\left| 1\right|}{\left| 1+j\omega\right|}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\omega^2}}\\
  \phi&=\angle{z}=\angle{\frac{1}{1+j\omega}}=\angle{1}-{\angle{1+j\omega}}=0-\tan^{-1}\left(\omega \right)=-\tan^{-1}\left(\omega \right)
  \end{align}

You can verify that $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\phi=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x} \right)$.

Comment: i didn't realize i had to rationalize the denominator first if i was to use the x+yj to convert to polar. 

Also the way you calculated polar you didn't need to actually get it to rectangular form first which seems a lot easier in some cases.

Thanks that cleared up my doubt.

Comment: @skyknight You are welcome. Generally: Using the polar form is easier for multiplication & division, whereas the rectangular form is easier for summation & subtraction.